# Solving advection-diffusion equation $ P_t (x,t) = DP_{xx} -V P_x$ for $P_t(x,t=0)=-V\delta'(x)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

I would like to solve the advection diffusion equation
$$ \partial_t P(x,t) = -V \partial_x P(x,t) + D \partial_x^2P(x,t) $$
for the conditions $P(x,0) = \delta(x)$, $P(x\rightarrow\infty,t) = 0$,  and $\partial_t P(x,t)|_{t=0} = -V\delta'(x)$, but I am not sure how to proceed.

So far, I attempted to use separation of variables with $P(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, finding
$$ T' - \lambda T = 0$$
and
$$ DX'' - VX' - \lambda X = 0.$$
I think this gives a product solution

$$P(x,t) = \int_0^\infty K(\lambda)e^{-\lambda t} \exp\Big[\frac{Vx}{2D}\bigg(1-\sqrt{1+\frac{4D\lambda}{V^2}}\bigg)\Big]  d\lambda,$$
where $K$ is an unkown function of the parameter $\lambda$, but I am not sure if this is correct. In fact I think it is not, because there should be two free parameters remaining to fix by the conditions. Should it also involve a convolution over $x$? And if so, how would I know this from the mathematics?

Any advice here would be most welcome - I'm left with many questions. What is this combination of initial/boundary conditions called? Is there a reference for this solution? Is the product solution by separation of variables possible, and if so, where am I going wrong? Why does a simple Fourier-Laplace transform approach fail? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: The last initial condition, for $\partial P/\partial t$, seems redundant and not quite correct. If $P(x,0) = \delta(x)$, then the PDE forces the condition $P_t(x,0) = -V \delta'(x) + D \delta''(x)$ to hold automatically.

Comment: Anyway, can't you just change to new variables $(\xi,\tau)$ defined by $\xi = x-Vt$ and $\tau=t$? Unless I'm mistaken, that should reduce the equation to the ordinary heat equation, whose fundamental solution is known.

Comment: @HansLundmark absolutely the transformation you suggest removes the advection term and produces a heat equation, but the initial condition $\partial_t P(x,0) \sim - \delta'(x) $ for the heat equation is not available in the standard texts. I think actually the condition cannot be met due to your first comment. One would need another time derivative. For example $( \partial_t^2 + V \partial_t \partial_x - D \partial_t \partial_x^2 ) P(x,t) = 0 $ would allow for meeting the initial condition on the first derivative. Otherwise the problem I posed cannot be solved

Comment: The solution of the equation meeting $\partial_t P(x,0) = -V \delta'(x)$ of the equation 
 with another time derivative would be $P(x,t) = \Big[ 1 + D \partial_x^2 \int_0^t dt \Big]G(x,t)$ where $G(x,t)$ is the solution of the advection-diffusion equation with $G(x,0) = \delta(x)$.

Comment: If you *really* want $P_t(x,0) = -\delta'(x)$ for the heat equation (which by the way may not actually be the condition that you get when changing variables, since $\partial_t \neq \partial_{\tau}$), then you can solve it with $P(x,0) = -\tfrac12 \operatorname{sgn}(x)$, since then $P_t(x,0)=P_{xx}(x,0)=-\delta'(x)$. But then $u$ doesn't tend to zero as $x \to \pm\infty$. Anyway, already from the start of your question it seems very weird to have *two* initial conditions for an equation which is of first order in $t$. Where does this all come from?

Comment: I solved $(\partial_t^2 + V \partial_x \partial_t + k_E V \partial_x + (k_E+k_D) \partial_t - D \partial_x^2 \partial_t - k_E D \partial_x^2) P(x,t) = 0$ for the initial conditions $P(x,0)=\delta(x)$ and $\partial_t P(x,0)=-V\delta'(x)$.  This reduces to the equation above in the limit $k_E \rightarrow \infty$, yet in the limit those same initial conditions can no longer be met.

Comment: I see. Limiting cases where the order of the differential equation changes are usually tricky. Maybe you should ask a new question about how to handle that limit properly, which seems to be what you actually want to know. This question here seems to be a bit of an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Regarding your original equation: you have taken $k_E>>k_D$ but presumed that $\partial_{tt}P$ is subdominant, which may not be valid in general. It is clear that this is a singular perturbation problem as you lose the highest derivative in doing so. Since your 'unperturbed' equation (in your question) has no solution that satisfies the initial conditions, we might expect some sort of boundary layer forms at $t=0$. As @Hans mentions, better to start a new question about an approximate solution to your original equation.